# JUnit How to mock properties of superclass

Tags: junit

```
class A {

     int a;
     int b;

 }



class B extends A {

     public int add(){
         return a+b;
     }
 }
```

I want to test method add in subclass B but  how can i mock properties a, b from superclass A.

Comment: do you want to mock them? Can't you use setters?

Comment: I am using Reflection to set value for properties now. But subclass just take default value.

Comment: I think this will be possible with PowerMock... Is there a reason you are using reflection? Are you sure this is the best option? Also, why are you giving members a and b default access? I'm not saying they shouldn't, but just think about your design... Most of the times, when I need to use PowerMock, it's because something is off in my design...

Comment: Actually a and b are protected access. And we don't use getter and setter for those properties. That's why i have to use Reflection. Really thanks for your answer.

Comment: a and b don't have the protected keyword... So the default access modifier is used... I would look into powermock, that would be a startingpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather recommend you to use the `getters` and `setters` for those fields.

Anyway, show the code where you set and get the values through reflection.

Here's what your reflective part of the code should look like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
  {
    B bObj = new B();
    Field aField = A.class.getDeclaredField("a");
    Field bField = A.class.getDeclaredField("b");
    aField.set(bObj, 5);
    bField.set(bObj, 10);

    // alternatively, if you had getters, you can see the values using them
    System.out.println(aField.getInt(bObj));
    System.out.println(bField.getInt(bObj));
  }
```

This would print `5` and `10` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what exactly what i did. i've already set value for a and b but subclass just take default value only. I want to test method add() with new value.